# How can I use a variable which is defined in .cs file in .aspx file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Default.aspx want to use a variable `daysBefore` which is defined in *PublicPar.cs* , how can I do ?

BTW, at present Default.aspx is not correct.

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Links.aspx.cs" Inherits="LinkTabs.Links" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
   
    <div id="forNote">
       <span style="color:red;">Note:</span> Days: <%= daysBefore.toString() %>
   </div> 

</asp:Content>
```

**PublicPar.cs**

```
namespace LinkTabs.App_MyCode.BLL
{
    public class PublicPar
    {
        public const int daysBefore = 30;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the variable is defined in a different class, you can not directly access it without reference of the class. You need to do `<%= PublicPar.daysBefore.toString() %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that should work fine. But, intel-sense should have perhaps saved you!

So, try this:

```
<div id="forNote">
    <span style="color: red;">Note:</span> Days: <%= daysBefore.ToString() %>
</div>
```

Note the "casing" in the .ToString().

However, while typing, intel-sense should suggest and offer the correct syntax here.